# MATLAB ODE check conditions at next step / iterate if neccesarry

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm trying to solve a physical flow problem (Boundary Layer flow in a pipe) in Matlab. To do that, I have to solve a system of ODEs which looks somewhat like this:

```
function dy = ODEFUN(t,y)
    dy = dp + c;
end
```

The problem is, that dp is also unknown and hast to be set to fullfill some physical conditions at the next step. There is no explicit equation for dp, but I can only check if it is correct at the next time step t+1. If it is not correct I would need to go back to the previous time step and adapt dp.

As it seems the standard ODE solvers like ODE15s cannot do this or at least I have not found a way to tell them. Is there any possibility to implement this algorithm?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is a `while`-loop an option for you?

Comment: A while loop could be an option if the ODE was solved with a fixed step size. But due to the stiffness of the system a step size is chosen by the Matlab solver ODE15s. And I don't know any option to tell it to return to the previous step (which would be very helpful...)

Comment: I'm not sure if this sort of problem is suitable for ODE solvers (is your system even an ODE system?). This sounds more like a [boundary value problem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/boundary-value-problems.html).